# Limit component-links added to a component based upon custom rules?

Tags: 2013, cme, gui-extensions

I have a component that uses a schema that contains a component link field with "Allow Multiple Values" checked.  The components added via the component link have a drop down with states. If possible, we'd like to add a condition so that a state can not be added more than once.  Is this possible?

Comment: So you don't want the linking component to *not* use linked Components with the same value? Or do the linked Component need to have unique values? If the latter, there's a "identification" option on Categories that ensures keywords aren't used more than once. The Components tagged with these keywords can't have the same name either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible by implementing an Event System. Basically you will need to implement an Event Handler for the `Component Save` event for the `Initialize` phase, there you can perform the validation and throw an exception if the state has been added more than once